# Stuck at comparing date of birth in the form yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: python

I am fairly new around and wanted to make a simple program that would compare date of births.
So far I have this block of code

```
y1 = int(input("Enter the year of birth of person 1 in the form of YYYY"+" "))

m1 =int(input("Enter the month of birth of person 1 in the form of MM"+" ")) 

d1 =int(input("Enter the day of birth of person 1 in the form of DD"+" "))

y2 = int(input("Enter the year of birth of person 2 in the form of YYYY"+" "))

m2 =int(input("Enter the month of birth of person 2 in the form of MM"+" ")) 

d2 =int(input("Enter the day of birth of person 2 in the form of DD"+" "))
```

I can manage do successfully compare dates of birth as long as the year of birth is different.I have no clue how to write the code so that if the year of birth is the same it will compare the month of birth.If the month of birth is the same it will compare the day of birth and print out accordingly.Tried searching around Google but with no luck to this specific question,only similar ones.

Keep in mind I barely know how to open the Python Gui Idle and save my projects so I would not be able to understand difficult answers especially if they reference more in depth knowledge of Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just [compare tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) of all three values!

```
(y1, m1, d1) < (y2, m2, d2)
```

First, this checks whether `y1 < y2`. If they are equal, it checks whether `m1 < m2`, and so on.

```
>>> (2001, 3, 13) < (2002, 3, 14)
True
>>> (2001, 3, 13) < (2001, 3, 12)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

The general Python syntax for a simple if statement is

```
if condition :
    indentedStatementBlock
```

So try something like this:

```
if month1 == month2 :
     if day1 == day2 :
         Do whatever you need to do if the dates are the same.
```